# Get Varbinary as String

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

How to get the "varbinary" content as it is from MySql, as java string while making a stored procedure call?

So, I am making a simple JDBC call with my StoredProcedure name and input parameters map(parametersMap):-
**Map map = call.execute(parametersMap);**

and I am getting a "varbinary" field as Object which has "B@6550f5eb" as value.. But I need it in String format as it is(say 0x64756D6D792064617461).

I tried doing getBytes() but it's not able to cast.

**This is my table** :-

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id int,
    key varchar(255),
    keyType varchar(20),
    content varbinary(max)
)
```

**This is my StoredProcedure:-**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE docContent
    @DocId AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT content
    FROM table1
    WHERE id  = @DocId
END
```

Comment: If the string representation of your object actually begins with `[B@`, then it's a byte array.

Comment: See [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)